# DiffSharp sliding window implementation example

Tags: pytorch, f#, tensor, diffsharp

According to this issue [Check view operations correspond to torch #199](https://github.com/DiffSharp/DiffSharp/issues/199)
It seems like it is not hard to implement sliding window function with DiffSharp Tensor. However I cannot get a hint searching DiffSharp official website.

In PyTorch, the unfold is like:

```
x = torch.arange(1., 20)
x.unfold(0,4,2)

tensor([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],  
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],  
        [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],  
        [ 7.,  8.,  9., 10.],  
        [ 9., 10., 11., 12.],  
        [11., 12., 13., 14.],  
        [13., 14., 15., 16.],  
        [15., 16., 17., 18.]])
```

How do I correctly implement unfold operator with DiffSharp Tensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using unfold provided by TensorSharp instead works fine.
[Implement miscellaneous utility functions](https://github.com/dotnet/TorchSharp/issues/560)